# Getting 404(Not Found) when executing POST ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i having trouble figuring out why i am getting this error(404). The method is clearly there so i dont know what is going on. At the bottom, i will be showing you my javascript and then my .cs method.

JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Vatican.aspx/Info",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: myString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Yay! It worked!');               
    },
error: function (result) {
    alert('Oh no :(');
}
});
```

.cs

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string Info()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string result = js.Serialize(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I'm no expert but jquery ajax has to send the data to Vatican.aspx (the actual file directly) and you'll have to parse the data sent to that file and then run the appropriate function (I think).

Comment: 404 means resource not found. Can you make sure URL is accessible first? Another error in your code. $.ajax doesn't have 'type', it should be 'method'.

Comment: @wannadream `type` is an alias to `method`. There are no difference according to the official jQuery Docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: Then you really need to check the URL first. 404 is not found, is the relative path you gave is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue with your ajax call.

`data: myString,` You are passing `myString` to your webMethod but within your webmethod you are not expecting any parameter, either remove `data` from your ajax call or put the declaration within web method like this:

```
public static string Info(string myString)
```

And within your ajax call set your data like:

```
 data:'{myString:'+ JSON.stringify(myString)+'}',
```

These changes will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it still doesnt work! `myString` is actually JSON. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Just remove `data:myString` from your ajax call, put a breakpoint at your `webmethod`, it will work.

Comment: Nope, it still wont work. I keep getting this error 'POST http://localhost:11111/Vatican.aspx/Info 404 (Not Found)'